# Disable browser controls in CEF

Tags: winapi, chromium, chromium-embedded

Just a quick question.
I saw some pictures of chromium embedded (CEF) implementation in Win32 and there is everywhere those browser buttons "Back" "Forward" "reload" and address bar (http://img300.imageshack.us/img300/6443/acidc.png).

Question is: Is it part of win32 application or part of CEF itself, and before I start to dig in CEF i need to know can I turn off all those buttons and use CEF only to show a window with web page in it, without any controls? (or make adress bar read only and hide all other controls).

Want to use CEF because chromium engine fast and supports all modern technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation buttons and address bar it is part of cefclient sample application, not of browser itself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify SetNavState inside client handler implementation. 
Also, for the context menu, you need to implement menu handler method OnBeforeMenu to enable/disable the Back/forward as well.

Comment: Appreciate your time, thanks for the answer, though question is 3 years old ;)